# How to write separately business logic in API controller as helper class or handler using interfaces

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing .net RESTful WebAPI with API controller with actions, using entity framework.

It will auto generate the controller, So I need to write a Business logic in controller(`EmployeeDetailController`) to helper(`EmployeeDetailHandler`) class and connect with Interface(`IEmployeeDetailHandler`).

So need to connect `Dbcontext` to helper class(`EmployeeDetailHandler`) without depending on controller to test the unit testing with xunit.

How can i Write Handler class and the controller class?

This is my Controller(API controller with actions, using entity framework).

I need to write the logic inside this in separately on helper class by connecting interface to controller class.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EmployeeDetailController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly AuthenticationContext _context;

    public EmployeeDetailController(AuthenticationContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/EmployeeDetail
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<EmployeeDetail> GetEmployeeDetails()
    {
        return _context.EmployeeDetails;
    }

    // GET: api/EmployeeDetail/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetEmployeeDetail([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var employeeDetail = await _context.EmployeeDetails.FindAsync(id);

        if (employeeDetail == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(employeeDetail);
    }

    // PUT: api/EmployeeDetail/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutEmployeeDetail([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] EmployeeDetail employeeDetail)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != employeeDetail.EId)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(employeeDetail).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!EmployeeDetailExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }

    // POST: api/EmployeeDetail
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostEmployeeDetail([FromBody] EmployeeDetail employeeDetail)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _context.EmployeeDetails.Add(employeeDetail);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetEmployeeDetail", new { id = employeeDetail.EId }, employeeDetail);
    }

    // DELETE: api/EmployeeDetail/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteEmployeeDetail([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var employeeDetail = await _context.EmployeeDetails.FindAsync(id);
        if (employeeDetail == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _context.EmployeeDetails.Remove(employeeDetail);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(employeeDetail);
    }

    private bool EmployeeDetailExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.EmployeeDetails.Any(e => e.EId == id);
    }
  }
```

}

This is my Context class

```
public class AuthenticationContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public AuthenticationContext(DbContextOptions options):base(options {}
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EmployeeDetail> EmployeeDetails { get; set; }
}
```

This is dB Model

```
public class EmployeeDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int EId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "Nvarchar(100)")]
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "Nvarchar(10)")]
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "Nvarchar(10)")]
    public string BDay { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "Nvarchar(10)")]
    public string Nic { get; set; }
}
```

Expect is relevant handler class( service/Hepler) with interfaces.

Comment: DBContext and unit test do not go in the same sentence

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing is for small bits of code you can test in isolation.

Forget about controllers, forget about DbContext and focus on your business logic.

Your controllers should be thin layers doing model validation and passing data to your business layer, nothing more. As such you should have no need to even look at them.

So, unit test the business logic. Cover every endpoint with integration tests, for correct and incorrect models, etc.

Orchestrate the integration tests with something like Postman or anything else that allows this.

The code you showed is not suitable for unit testing at all.